# Mesh simplification

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I wish to develop a softare for 3D object compression (by polygon reduction) in flex using papervision 3D. Could you please suggest me an efficient algorithm for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [A Short Survey of Mesh Simplification Algorithms](http://www.jerrytalton.net/research/Talton04SSMSA.report/Talton04SSMSA.pdf) and follow the references for the details.

Comment: The link should be [A Short Survey of Mesh Simplification Algorithms](http://www.jerrytalton.net/research/Talton04SSMSA.report/Talton04SSMSA.pdf). BTW, _Surface Simplification Using Quadric Error Metrics_ is actually pretty straightforward. You can find the implementation on M. Garland's [website](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~garland/quadrics/)

Comment: The link was valid when I posted it, but I've changed it to the above.